# Can I use custom name for theme directory?

Tags: 7, theming, files

I'm developing site using Drupal 7. I want to give a custom name for the themes directory. Is it possible with Drupal?

Comment: @Bala when you edit, please fix all problems with post - missing tags are also a problem.

Comment: @Mołot I thinks this question don't need theming tag, please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming core directories is not possible without hacking Drupal's core. [Hacking core is highly discouraged](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core). Even if it will work, one module that will try to access directory directly may mess up your installation.

Comment: why hacking core is discouraged?

Comment: @JhilkeDai [it's in the manual](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core). Long story short, if you have to ask, you don't have enough knowledge to do it *right*.

Comment: Thanks all. I got the answer as no. I will look-in to another solution

Comment: @user28542 feel free to ask anither question, telling us what are you trying to *accomplish* - This seems to be a classical XY issue: you have problem X, and you think that solution would be Y, so you are asking us how to do Y. Ask us how to solve X instead :)